# Blocking reverse transients in bidirectional circuit

Tags: dc-motor

I have a bit of a puzzle to try and work out for a friend, and it's beyond even my abilities to fathom - but then, it's an analogue problem and I don't "do" analogue...

Basically we have a circuit consisting of a motor with snubber capacitor across it, and two LEDs with resistors. Simple enough. The circuit is in a mobile unit which takes its power through unreliable connections to the outside world (that's a fancy way of saying "it's a toy train"...)

Power is PWM modulated for speed, and direction is controlled by reversing the polarity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foxyzD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As it stands it all works. The problem occurs when the incoming power is interrupted (represented by fuses X in the schematic) through bad connections with the rails. Now either the charge stored in the snubber capacitor C1 or the simple momentum of the vehicle causing the motor to keep spinning and turning into a generator makes the LED for the opposite direction illuminate.

These are only short period transients before the power is restored again, but they can happen frequently, resulting in a flickering of the wrong LED.

What would be the best way of suppressing this unwanted current flow, given the limited space in the train and over-simplicity of the motor circuit?

Comment: The outlet on a locomotive is usually unique on both rails. Providing 2 is the simplest "correction" possibility, since there are also two "axes" of wheels.

Comment: @Antonio51 Sorry, I really don't follow what you're saying there...

Comment: Can you "make" a picture of the "contacts" and where there are?

Comment: @Antonio51 No, I can't, since I don't have this information. However the "contacts" are basically circular rotating objects adjacent to tangential metal rods. I.e., wheels on the rails.

Comment: Make the capacitor bigger in value.

Answer (score 2):

When the power supply is interrupted, the charge on the snubber capacitor is not going to instantaneously reverse. Therefore it must be due to the motor either the back emf as the current is suddenly stopped through its inductance or, as you say, it acts like a generator, discharging the capacitor and then recharging it in the opposite direction to light the wrong LED.
This may not be the solution, but try increasing the value of the capacitor so that there is sufficient energy stored to maintain the polarity despite the efforts of the motor. I presume you have checked the existing capacitor to see that it is still good.

Comment: Worth a try. Unfortunately I don't have first hand direct access to this, so it's all "try this" through email. By all accounts the existing capacitor is the original (almost 50 year old I think) one, so sure we'll try upgrading that to something modern.

Comment: By all accounts, a 50 year old capacitor is most likely a dead capacitor. If you watch videos of people restoring old electronic equipment on YouTube (MrCarlsonsLab for example) capacitors are the first things that get replaced. Modern devices are so much better.

Comment: Not in my experience. Wax capacitors, sure, and electrolytics can dry out, especially ones from the "plague" era, but I restore vintage electronics and have seldom had to replace capacitors (only a few individuals where they are certainly dead). It's more common to have to replace electrolytics in modern electronics than polyesters / ceramics in vintage electronics.

Comment: Right now I am working on an HMV model 2026 which has had 1 bad resistor, 1 bad capacitor and 1 bad germanium PNP transistor (those are hard to get hold of these days...)

Answer (score 0):

I show this from this [site](https://3dmdb.com/en/3d-model/hoooon30-model-train-engine-power-bogie/4882275/) : example.

Something to see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoFl-v1AgbQ

[image]

Generally, there is only one group "slider". Only add a second group on the other wheels if there are obviously isolated, same "boggie".

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. I suspect such physical modifications are beyond the owner of this train. TBH I don't even know what gauge it is. It's been many decades since I myself had a train set, and from memory the trains I had were dual contact on two axels, not just on one. But I may be mistaken. It's probably different from train to train and gauge to gauge. That picture looks like N gage to me, and I have only first hand (from my childhood) of OO gauge...

Comment: On the smaller models, it seems to me that the power sockets are "brushes".